# JSON to Object MyBatis

Tags: java, json, mybatis

В базе PosgreSQL есть колонка с jsonb, я хочу получить содержимое этой колонки не как строку, а как объект(преобразовать json в объект на лету, чтобы потом не пробегать по списку с ответами и не делать объекты с помощью Jackson) используя myBatis. Возможно ли это?

Искала ответ в документации, ничего подходящего не нашла.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать свой [TypeHandler](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) или воспользоваться готовыми - [mybatis-jackson](https://github.com/javaplugs/mybatis-jackson), [mybatis-gso](https://github.com/javaplugs/mybatis-gson)n.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Если набор полей в объекте jsonb заранее известен, то с помощью SQL можно эти поля вытащить из json и преобразовать их в обычные колонки. А дальше маппить их на Java-объект стандартными средствами MyBatis.

Например, в таблице есть колонка **data** (jsonb):

```
{"id": "100", "tax": "4.5", "price": "10", "code": "YXCV"}
```

SQL запрос для представления полей jsonb в виде обычных колонок:

```
SELECT name, 
       description, 
       data ->> 'id' AS id,
       data ->> 'tax' AS tax,
       data ->> 'price' AS price,
       data ->> 'code' AS code,
FROM some_table;
```

Ответ на подобный вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945308/how-to-get-a-json-object-as-column-in-postgresql) (там есть ещё один вариант решения).